# file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile

I use makefile to compile my C++ program, but it shows a warning:

```
make
g++ -g -std=c++0x -o ns-client main.cpp Client.cpp TCPConnect.cpp RSAsample.cpp libStatic/libchilkat_i386.a libStatic/libchilkat_x86_64.a -lpthread
ld: warning: ignoring file libStatic/libchilkat_i386.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): libStatic/libchilkat_i386.a
```

My makefile is as follows:

```
cat Makefile 
LIBS = libStatic/libchilkat_i386.a libStatic/libchilkat_x86_64.a -lpthread
GPP = g++ -g -std=c++0x
TARGET = -o ns-client
CPP = main.cpp Client.cpp TCPConnect.cpp RSAsample.cpp

all:
$(GPP) $(TARGET) $(CPP) $(LIBS)
clean:
rm ns-client
```

`libchilkat_i386.a` and `libchilkat_x86_64.a` are downloaded by me, not implemented by me. I put them under a directory called "libStatic".
These are all my C++ files and lib:

```
ls
Client.cpp      RSAsample.cpp       libStatic
Client.h        RSAsample.h     main.cpp
Client_Common.h     TCPConnect.cpp      ns-client
Common_Num_Define.h TCPConnect.h        ns-client.dSYM
Common_Protocol.h   include         ns-server
Makefile        libDyn
```

In libStatic directory, it has:

```
ls
libchilkat_i386.a   libchilkat_x86_64.a
```

I don't know why this warning happens. Even though it has this warning, it still compile successfully. But when I upload them to our school's server and compile them(I definitely upload these static libs), it shows:

```
 undefined reference to
```

Many these kinds of errors. For example:

```
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/Client.cpp:17: undefined reference to `CkRsa::exportPublicKey()'
```

All these functions and vars which are mentioned in these kinds of errors  should be included in `libchilkat_i386.a libchilkat_x86_64.a`
So I doubt maybe it is because of my Makefile.But I am not sure. I also doubt that maybe related to the first warning. Can somebody tells me how solve the first warning or why it cannot compile on another machine but can compile on my own machine? Thanks for everyone's help!

This is all errors it showed on our school's server:

```
/tmp/ccA32Kao.o: In function `My_RSA::My_RSA()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6My_RSAC2Ev[_ZN6My_RSAC5Ev]+0x19): undefined reference to `CkRsa::CkRsa()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6My_RSAC2Ev[_ZN6My_RSAC5Ev]+0x2b): undefined reference to `CkRsa::CkRsa()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6My_RSAC2Ev[_ZN6My_RSAC5Ev]+0x3d): undefined reference to `CkRsa::CkRsa()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6My_RSAC2Ev[_ZN6My_RSAC5Ev]+0x54): undefined reference to `CkRsa::~CkRsa()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6My_RSAC2Ev[_ZN6My_RSAC5Ev]+0x69): undefined reference to `CkRsa::~CkRsa()'
/tmp/ccA32Kao.o: In function `My_RSA::~My_RSA()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6My_RSAD2Ev[_ZN6My_RSAD5Ev]+0x1a): undefined reference to `CkRsa::~CkRsa()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6My_RSAD2Ev[_ZN6My_RSAD5Ev]+0x2c): undefined reference to `CkRsa::~CkRsa()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN6My_RSAD2Ev[_ZN6My_RSAD5Ev]+0x3c): undefined reference to `CkRsa::~CkRsa()'
/tmp/cciEnFVR.o: In function `Client::Register()':
                /home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/Client.cpp:17: undefined reference to `CkRsa::exportPublicKey()'
    /home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/Client.cpp:18: undefined reference to `CkRsa::exportPrivateKey()'
```

/tmp/cciEnFVR.o: In function `Client::Login()':
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/Client.cpp:128: undefined reference to`CkRsa::exportPublicKey()'
    /home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/Client.cpp:129: undefined reference to `CkRsa::exportPrivateKey()'
    /tmp/cciEnFVR.o: In function`Client::Judge_Command(char*)':
    /home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/Client.cpp:930    : undefined reference to `CkRsa::exportPrivateKey()'
    /home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/Client.cpp:931: undefined reference to`CkRsa::exportPublicKey()'
    /tmp/ccRMXreb.o: In function `My_RSA::MyEncryption(char const*, char const*)':
    /home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:    16: undefined reference to`CkRsa::put_EncodingMode(char const*)'
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:    17: undefined reference to `CkRsa::ImportPublicKey(char const*)'
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:    25: undefined reference to`CkRsa::encryptStringENC(char const*, bool)'
/tmp/ccRMXreb.o: In function `My_RSA::MyDecryption(char*)':
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:    33: undefined reference to`CkRsa::put_EncodingMode(char const*)'
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:    34: undefined reference to `CkRsa::ImportPrivateKey(char const*)'
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:    42: undefined reference to`CkRsa::decryptStringENC(char const*, bool)'
/tmp/ccRMXreb.o: In function `My_RSA::My_Initial_Key()':
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:    52: undefined reference to`CkRsa::UnlockComponent(char const*)'
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:    58: undefined reference to `CkRsa::GenerateKey(int)'
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:    61: undefined reference to`CkMultiByteBase::lastErrorText()'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [all] Error 1

All these functions which should belong to CKRsa are in `#include "include/CkRsa.h"`, but I definitely create the "include" directory on our school's server and upload these CKRsa.h files in that directory.

I revise my makefile,but it still doesn't work:

```
cat Makefile 
LFLAGS += -L     /home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/libStatic 
LIBS = libStatic/libchilkat_x86_64.a  -lpthread
GPP = g++ -g -std=c++0x
TARGET = -o ns-client
CPP = main.cpp Client.cpp TCPConnect.cpp Common_Protocol.h RSAsample.cpp TCPConnect.h Client.h RSAsample.h include/CkRsa.h

all:
    $(GPP) $(LFLAGS)  $(TARGET) $(CPP) $(LIBS)
```

I revise makefile again, but it still doesn't work:

```
 cat Makefile 
 LFLAGS += -L           /home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/libStatic 
 LIBS = -lchilkat_x86_64  -lpthread
 GPP = g++ -g -std=c++0x
 TARGET = -o ns-client
 CPP = main.cpp Client.cpp TCPConnect.cpp Common_Protocol.h RSAsample.cpp TCPConnect.h Client.h RSAsample.h include/CkRsa.h

 all:
     $(GPP) $(LFLAGS)  $(TARGET) $(CPP) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to compile a 64 bit program but, you are linking an incorrect library for 32 bits.

Comment: I delete libStatic/libchilkat_i386.a from my makefile, but it still  cannot compile on our school's server.

Comment: You will need to replace it with a correct version for x64, i don't know exactly what libchilkat is but: (link)[http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_CPP.asp] seems to have your necessary library...

Comment: This link shows:404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: sorry i didn't put the link correctly. it is  chilkatsoft.com/downloads_CPP.asp

Comment: My version does be downloaded from that link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72183/discussion-between-carlos-baez-and-beasone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library problem (built for a different architecture) is easily fixed by NOT using the library that you don't want. If you are publishing a makefile, you'll have to use some sort of configuration setting to determine the right architecture. If it's just your own project, pick the one that matches your system (by the looks of your makefile, the x86_variant).

The error `CkRsa::exportPublicKey` is caused by your client code: The official symbol is `CkRsa::ExportPublicKey` - note the uppercase `E` at the beginning of the function name.

Here's the header file:
http://smart-refrigerator-hbnu.googlecode.com/svn/branches/kmy/RFID_CLIENT_/include/CkRsa.h

Comment: it also shows:/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:52: undefined reference to `CkRsa::UnlockComponent(char const*)'
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:58: undefined reference to `CkRsa::GenerateKey(int)'
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:61: undefined reference to `CkMultiByteBase::lastErrorText()'

Comment: /home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:33: undefined reference to `CkRsa::put_EncodingMode(char const*)'
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:34: undefined reference to `CkRsa::ImportPrivateKey(char const*)'
/home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/RSAsample.cpp:42: undefined reference to `CkRsa::decryptStringENC(char const*, bool)'

Comment: I see these two functions :const char *exportPublicKey(void);
 const char *exportPrivateKey(void); in your link. These functions does be declared in the CKRsa class.

Comment: what does `nm libchilkat_x86_64.a|c++filt` say the actual library contains? Maybe you have a different version with a different name?

Comment: Also, you probably want to use `-lchilkat_x86_64` instead of linking the .a file directly.

Comment: it shows :/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lchilkat_x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1  after I add -lchilkat_x86_64 in my Makefile

Comment: All these functions which should belong to CKRsa are in #include "include/CkRsa.h", but I definitely create the "include" directory on our school's server and upload these CKRsa.h files in that directory. Should I revise something about header file's location in my Makefile?

Comment: Perhaps you need `-L .` as well then to make sure it looks for libraries in the current directory. Where you `CkRsa.h` is located should not make any difference - as long as it's the right one. The problem you are seeing is definitely either to do with how you are linking the files, or that your lib-file doesn't contain what you think it should contain.#

Comment: cat Makefile 
LFLAGS += -L /home/users/liuly/liuly/networksecurity/project/cplus/client/libStatic 
LIBS = libchilkat_i386.a libchilkat_x86_64.a -lpthread
GPP = g++ -g -std=c++0x
TARGET = -o ns-client
CPP = main.cpp Client.cpp TCPConnect.cpp Common_Protocol.h RSAsample.cpp TCPConnect.h Client.h RSAsample.h include/CkRsa.h

all:
 $(GPP) $(LFLAGS)  $(TARGET) $(CPP) $(LIBS)       still doesn't work

Comment: And I'm 99% sure that you should NOT use `libchikat_x86_64.a` but `-lchilkat_x86_64` - otherwise, the linker may not find the correct parts of the library, as they may not be listed in the order they are needed by your application or by themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I just put the new makefile in the question part,I add -L in the new Makefile,please see the edit.

Comment: Right, you are linking using `-lpthread`, that links `libpthread.a` - you need to do the same thing for this library, ok?

Comment: I revised it into LIBS = -lchilkat_x86_64  -lpthread, but it still doesn't work. See my edit in my question, it has all my makefile content.

Comment: How to use nm? Sorry I don't understand how to add nm into my makefile.

Comment: Not adding to your makefile, just run `nm yourlibfile` or `nm yourlibfile|c++filt` to see what the names are of the exported symbols in your library.

Comment: it comes out a bunch of words, about thousands of lines. like:00000000000002fb T _CkSocketW_getClientPort
0000000000001808 S _CkSocketW_getClientPort.eh
0000000000000322 T _CkSocketW_getConnectFailReason
0000000000001858 S _CkSocketW_getConnectFailReason.eh(I only show you a part of them) Someone told me that I should tell the linker where is my Static lib, but i don't know how to tell the linker in my makefile.

Comment: "where your static lib is" is the -L option to gcc. So, dump the `nm` output to a file, and check if your symbols that you expect (exportPublicKey, etc) are actually there (or pass the output of nm through grep)

Comment: Now I see why this happens. My professor tells me that the static library which is downloaded from internet is only used for MAC OS (my own laptop is MAC), but our school's server is ubuntu. So i need to download the ubuntu version,otherwise our server cannot recognize the static lib.nm -a libchilkat-9.5.0.so |less using this command to check whether it can be recognized.

Comment: sorry, when I try your command :nm libchilkat_x86_64.a|c++filt, I use it on my own laptop instead of my school's server.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see why this happens. My professor tells me that the static library which is downloaded from internet is only used for MAC OS (my own laptop is MAC), but our school's server is ubuntu. So i need to download the ubuntu version,otherwise our server cannot recognize the static lib.  nm -a  libchilkat_x86_64.a |less using this command to check whether it can be recognized.
When I use this command on our server,it shows:

nm: C_CkString.o: File format not recognized    etc